# How to group collection by columns with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

My table named stocks contains `product_id, color_id, storage_id and in_stock` as columns.

For a given product I want to group all stocks by storage, then for each storage I want to show product (color): in_stock

How should I write a method and how to render?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<% Stock.all.group_by(&:storage).each do |storage, products| %>
  Storage: <%= storage %>
  <% products.each do |product| %>
    (<%= product.color_id %>): <%= product.in_stock %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: updated to use ERB, and in_stock as a number and not a boolean yes/no column, and use color_id in place of color.name because that assumes you have a relationship to a color.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Through the console it works as expected however through the UI it renders `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fcb0fe955e8> {#<Storage id: 1, name: "Warehouse", updated_at: "2011-11-08 21:18:07">=>[#<Stock id: 1, product_id: 1, color_id: 10, storage_id: 1, in_stock: 5.0>, #<Stock id: 586, product_id: 1, color_id: 1, storage_id: 1, in_stock: 0.0>, #<Stock id: 591, product_id: 1, color_id: 2, storage_id: 1, in_stock: 0.0>]...` It looks like it complains about relationship but not sure which one. Any idea?

Comment: @Gaelle I've updated my answer to use ERB and a couple of clues from this comment. If you have more problems, please be more descriptive. If you have an error message, please post it.

Comment: Quick follow up question. Say there was a column for price. How would one go about summing up the total prices for each group?

Answer (score 2):

Not structured exactly how you need it (not enough info from your post), but something like this perhaps?

```
items = Stock.select('color_id, in_stock').group('stocks.storage_id').where(:product_id => foo)

items.each {|item| puts "(#{lookup_color(item.color_id)}): #{in_stock}"
```